# Выставление счета посетителями сайта в программу 1С

Tags: php, 1с

Как отправить данные из обычной html формы методом POST в программу 1С и затем от него получить ответ. Т.е. надо чтобы посетители сайта могли сами выставить счет на оплату. Заполняют форму, отправляют в 1С, там данные записываются в базу и при успешной записи в базу приходит на сайт ответ с введенными данными.
Интересует самое простое решение именно со стороны сайта, а не со стороны 1С, как отправить запрос и каким образом (в каком формате) его можно получить обратно из 1С. Может кто сталкивался с этим, хотелось бы увидеть самый простой рабочий пример (на PHP). Заранее спасибо всем ответившим.

Comment: У вас на своём сервере и сайт и 1с?

Comment: Нет, сайт на обычном сервере от хостинг-провайдера reg.ru

Comment: Тогда как вариант настроить обмен протоколом e-commerce как можно чаще или на сайте создавать свои номера которые потом будут присвоены в 1с и так далее

Comment: Хотя в принципе это одно и тоже что протокол e-commerce что разные номера, так как насколько помню они и настраиваются на разные префиксы

Comment: @Walfter, а Вы можете показать рабочий код, например, для этой формы:
`<form action="action.php">
 <input type="text" name="product_name">
 <input type="text" name="company_name">
 <input type="submit" value="Выставить счет">
</form>`
Т.е. допустим, посетитель сайта заполнил эту форму, как теперь отправить эти данные в 1C? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нужно заставить 1с делать обмен с сайтом, пусть она сама берёт нужные данные из базы сайта

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так у заказчика я делал
В обработке 1с по заданному времени выполняется процедура отправить
Обработка запускается из "Запланированных задач"

```
Процедура Отпавить()
    Попытка
        WinHttp = Новый COMОбъект("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
        WinHttp.Option(2,"utf-8");
        WinHttp.Open("POST","http://org_docs.rf-ra.ru",0);
        WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "ru");
        WinHttp.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");
        WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Language", "ru");
        WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Charset", "utf-8");
        WinHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        ПараметрыПОСТ = "&jsondata=" + ДанныеJSON();
        WinHttp.Send(ПараметрыПОСТ);
        ТекстОтвета = WinHttp.ResponseText();
        ОбработатьОтвет(ТекстОтвета);
    Исключение
        Сообщить(ОписаниеОшибки());
    КонецПопытки;
КонецПроцедуры
```

И скрипт принимающий

```
<?php
// Класс Exchange это самописный класс который обрабатывает отправляемые с 1с данные

if ($_POST) {
    $question = json_decode($_POST['jsondata'], true);
    Exchange::save_question($question);
    $answer = Exchange::get_answer($question['type'], $question['user'], $question['chasbox']);
    die($answer);
}
die('<?xml version="1.0"?><docs count="0" /><message content="Неверные входные данные" code="004"/>')
```

?>

Выдернуто с рабочего примера(Кроме адреса)

Это всё делалось что бы организация зашла в личный кабинет, выбрала что им надо какие товары какие услуги, получила готовый документ(счёт на оплату и я сейчас не вспомню что ещё) распечатала, поставила печати и пришла в rf-ra получить уже по этому документу что им надо, 1с получает список, забивает его себе в мозги, бронирует товар.

Так сказать ускоряет подписание документов с двух сторон

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, на стороне 1С, нужно (если вам нужно синхронно) запустить HTTP сервис, который как раз принимает от сайта данные, делает все что нужно и возвращает ответ, в таком виде, в котором нужно. То есть, тут работа идет как PHP программиста, так и 1С. 
У нас так многие обмены идут, это достаточно быстро и удобно.

Со стороны 1С - [Ссылка на ИТС](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:5756:hdoc)